# Is it possible to create a '0100 error page'?

Tags: custom-error-pages, sentora

There are a diversity of custom error pages, such as 404. But what about other errors?

Sometimes my server (or it's database) crashes, most likely due to many Wordpress actions made in a short time. In such case any user will see the error message, as seen in the image below.

I would like to modify such page with clear instructions, instead of a big red box. But how would I create such error page?

Thanks!

---

*Fyi, I use the 'Sentora' control panel.*

[image]

Comment: That entirely depends on the configuration of the web server and/or how these error pages are generated. A "big red box" is certainly not a standard error page on any system I'm familiar with. You'll at least have to clarify what software all this is running on.

Comment: As written, perhaps not clear enough, just above the image, I use the Sentora Control panel, which 'owns' this error page.